# assign value to variable when variable is declared

Tags: makefile

I understand that if you assign value to a variable like below, it is assigned the value at declaration time:

```
 VER:=value
```

but when I do:

```
VER:=`python xxx.py`        

....
cd ../../pythoncode && python yyy.py $(VER)
```

I got error saying no xxx.py file found, it is because that xxx.py is in the current folder, but when cd ../../pythoncode,  xxx.py cannot be found.

How do I set the value of VER when VER is declared? so this way, VER value is set before cd ../../pythoncode,  Thanks.

LJ

Comment: Why are you passing `$(VER)` (i.e. `python xxx.py`) as an argument to `python xxx.py` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing variable assignment time and python runtime path lookup.

Your variable's value **is** being set at make parse time. That's not the problem.

The problem is that the path to your script is a relative path and path resolution/lookup is done by whatever process needs to use the file when it needs to use the file. So when you run `python` in that recipe line that python process sees `xxx.py` and assumes that it is relative to the current directory since you haven't told it anything else.

You could use `VER:= python $(abspath xxx.py)` to have make resolve `xxx.py` at make parse time and turn it into an absolute path. Then when you run `python` later it would get an absolute path to the script instead of a relative one.

There are other ways of solving this problem as well but for this case that is probably the simplest.